# Too many address books in Outlook (Exchange)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, address-book

I deliver Exchange Online to my customers, and I get a lot of complaints about there being too many address Books.

I don't have so many (see picture), but still an unnecessary amount.

How can I remove them? For example:  have only 1 address book per email-address (Exchange-account)

Picture:

[image]

This is how it looks under > `File` > `Account Settings` > `Address Books`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you use Outlook with an Exchange Account, the default is the Global Address List. The Global Address List will show all those address book entries by default and Offline if you use Cached Mode.

If you want the local Contacts to be searched first, you can go to Address Book, Tools, Options and change the lookup order.

Since you did not specify which version of Outlook is being used, I am not providing the exact steps. They vary slightly by the Outlook client version.